# Operating Systems: Peterson's solution

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, critical-section

I am trying to understand the peterson's solution for synchronisation. For reference, I am attaching the source of reading:
[image]

This is from the wikipedia page. Now,
Let's say P1 wants to enter the critical section. It sets `flag1 = true` and `turn=0`. If P0 is already in its critical section, P1 will continuously wait in its while loop  `while(flag[0] == true && turn ==0)`  as `flag[0] = true`.
My doubt is:

1. What will happen in the case: P1 is executing its while loop and when P0 just tries to enter the critical section and executed the
   line `flag[0] = true` . Due to some reason, it couldnt't execute the next line and terminated. In this, flag[0] is also true and
   turn is also 0. P1 unnecessarily waits while no process is inside
   the critical section.
2. Why it needs to check for the `turn` variable. Why not only this:  `while(flag[0]== true)` As soon as P0 will
       leave from critical section, flag[0] = false and P1 will be able to
       enter.

I am little confused in this synchronisation problem, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2. Why it needs to check for the turn variable. Why not only this:  while(flag[0]== true) As soon as P0 will leave from critical section, flag[0] = false and P1 will be able to enter

If you were to use just flag[0] and flag[1] it would lead to a deadlock. Let us consider P0 sets the flag[0] = true and goes ahead to check the condition in while loop. Before P0 can load the flag[1] value in a register for comparison, P1 sets flag[1] = true. So now P0 loads the value true and will keep waiting and since the flag[0] too is true and P0 is stuck in the while loop, P1 too will wait on the while loop. This is a deadlock condition since both are waiting for the other to change the flag value to false.

> 1. What will happen in the case: P1 is executing its while loop and when P0 just tries to enter the critical section and executed the line flag[0] = true . Due to some reason, it couldnt't execute the next line and terminated. In this, flag[0] is also true and turn is also 0. P1 unnecessarily waits while no process is inside the critical section.

For this question I don't think P0 terminating abruptly proves the implementation of the Peterson's solution for synchronization to be wrong. It is flaw in the program and any buggy code could lead to such a deadlock condition.

Answer (score 0):

http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hamilton/courses/330/notes/synchro/node3.html

The following link explains, by illustrating 3 cases, why we need the turn variable for the Peterson's solution. Basically, if the turn variable was not used, it would lead to a deadlock.